# Count ; form a tsv file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, path

Im trying to count the average length of paths in a tsv file. Articles in a path are separated by ";".
The tsvfile looks like this.

FORMAT:   [hashedIpAddress]        [timestamp]      [durationInSec]    [path]   [rating]

```
  6a3701d319fc3754  1297740409  166 14th_century;15th_century;16th_century;Pacific_Ocean;Atlantic_Ocean;Accra;Africa;Atlantic_slave_trade;African_slave_trade   NULL
  3824310e536af032  1344753412  88  14th_century;Europe;Africa;Atlantic_slave_trade;African_slave_trade 3
  415612e93584d30e  1349298640  138 14th_century;Niger;Nigeria;British_Empire;Slavery;Africa;Atlantic_slave_trade;African_slave_trade   NULL
```

My code so fare:

```
 import csv
 count=0
 with open('paths_finished.tsv', 'rb') as tsvfile:
     a = csv.reader(tsvfile,dialect='excel-tab')
     for row in a:
     # if row[3:4] == ';':
       # count++
         print row[1:4]
```

How do i count the  ';' in the file?

Comment: Did you want to count the number of paths, or the number of semicolons? The two numbers are related, of course, but if you wanted to know one or the other there are different approaches for both answers.

Comment: i want to find the average length of a path. So actualy i want to find path length for each line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *indexing*, not slicing, to get an individual column:

```
for row in a:
    article_count = len(row[3].split(';'))
```

Splitting the specific column text on `';'` gives you a list of elements; `len()` tells you how many elements there are.

Alternatively, count the `;` characters, add one:

```
for row in a:
    article_count = row[3].count(';') + 1
```

but perhaps you wanted to do something with the path elements themselves too.

To get the average length of all paths, I'd just use `.count()`:

```
total = 0
count = 0

for row in a:
    total += row[3].count(';') + 1
    count += 1

average = total / float(count)
```

You don't even have to use the `csv` module in that case; you don't need to split the lines into row at all, there are no `;` semicolons in the other columns, so the simpler solution is to just loop over the lines of the files:

```
with open('paths_finished.tsv', 'rb') as tsvfile:
    total = 0
    count = 0

    for line in tsvfile:
        total += line.count(';') + 1
        count += 1

    average = total / float(count)
```

Comment: im just asking but does this gives me the average length of paths per line?

Comment: @user3322871: `total` counts the total number of paths, `count` tracks the number of lines you have. The average per line is `total / count` (with `float(count)` making sure we do not use floor division).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `split` method:

```
paths = row[3].split(";")
print len(paths) - 1
```

This will count the number of `;` characters in the row. Remove the `-1` part if you want to count the elements that are split by `;`

Comment: Why the `- 1`? You are counting elements, not counting `;` characters.

Comment: Well, the question is a bit ambiguous on this. See: "How do i count the ';' in the file?"

Comment: Sure, but the other information makes it clear the OP wants to know how many paths there are in the file. You can get that info by counting `;` too, but then you'd *add* 1.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use `;` as the delimiter and use `len(row) - 1` if your only goal is counting semicolons.

i.e.

```
with open('paths_finished.tsv', 'rb') as tsvfile:
     a = csv.reader(tsvfile,dialect='excel-tab',delimiter=';')
     for row in a:
         print len(row)-1 # subtract 1 for counting ';'
```